# Exercise I-5 of Eisenbud-Harris

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have just started learning about schemes, so please do not be too harsh with me. I am trying to do Exercise I-5 of Eisenbud-Harris, "The geometry of schemes".

Suppose $X$ is the topological space $\{0,1\}$, topologized with its discrete topology. The authors say that $X$ is in fact $\text{spec}(R)$ for some rings $R$, and ask us to give examples of such rings.

I have no idea of how to do this. I think there must be some identification of the prime ideals to be made, in order to only get 2 elements in the underlying topological space, but I can not see how to proceed. Would be grateful to any help.

Answer (score 3):

Take $R = k\times k$ where $k$ is any field. Then $R$ has exactly two prime ideals : $k\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times k$, and they are clearly maximal. So $Spec(R)$ consists of two closed points.

In general, $Spec(R_1\times R_2) = Spec(R_1)\coprod Spec(R_2)$, so you can easily build affine schemes having the connected components you want.

Comment: Oh, thanks...I thought the answer would be something like the affine line, i.e. $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I guess I have too little experience.

Comment: The affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{Z}$ is a pretty complicated scheme : it encodes in particular the arithmetic of $\mathbb{Z}$ *and* all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ (which are *very* complicated).

Comment: Somehow I thought one can arrive to the topological space {$0,1$} from $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Z}}^1$. Perhaps by some other construction - I am probably mixing things up.