# A sheaf on $\{0,1\}$

Tags: definition, sheaf-theory

This is Exercise I-5 in *The Geometry of Schemes* by Eisenbud and Harris.

Let $X$ be the two-element set $\{0,1\}$, and make $X$ into a topological space by taking each of the four subsets to be open. A sheaf on $X$ is thus a collection of four sets with certain maps between them; describe the relations among those objects. ($X$ is actually $\mathrm{Spec}\,R$ for some rings $R$; can you find one?)

I am not exactly sure how a solution to this exercise should look like. I am new to sheaves, and maybe the definition needs some clarification.

So the topology is $\tau=\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, X\}$.

Now I can write down all the restriction maps, and associated sets $\mathcal{F}(U)$ for $U\in\tau$.

What exactly is $\mathcal{F}(\emptyset)$ for example, or $\mathcal{F}(X)$?
Are those just sets, and it does not matter, or is there a way to figure out more information about these sets?

The same goes for the restriction maps $\operatorname{res}_{\,U,V}$

What exactly are the sections of $\mathcal{F}(U)$? These seem to be "functions", but the definition of a presheaf in the book does not really specify this. So what is the domain, or codomain?

By the sheaf axiom we would have that for example the sections $f_X\in\mathcal{F}(X)$ and $f_0\in\mathcal{F}(\{0\})$ have to be equal on the intersection $X\cap\{0\}=\{0\}$.

Are sections in $\mathcal{F}(X)$ functions $f:X\to X$ and sections in $\mathcal{F}(\{0\})$ functions $f:\{0\}\to X$, or does this simply not matter?

As far as the additional question goes, I have noticed that this was asked before: [Exercise I-5 of Eisenbud-Harris](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747629/exercise-i-5-of-eisenbud-harris)

But this is not the point of my question here. I want to get more familiarity with the definition of a sheaf.

Thanks in advance for any clarification/insights on sheaves.